# How to obtain VIF using biglm package?

Tags: r, regression

I refer to this post http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Questions-about-biglm-td878929.html which discusses on how to obtain VIF using biglm.

Is there an alternative way of obtaining VIF from the object produced by biglm?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For simple models, this is relatively easy following the code in the `vif()` method of `"lm"` objects in the **car** package, as John Fox suggested in the R-Help thread you linked to. You can't use the **car** package directly as it uses the model matrix and that isn't going to be possible with `biglm()`. To illustrate how to do this, consider the simple example from `?biglm`

```
require(biglm)
data(trees)
ff <- log(Volume) ~ log(Girth) + log(Height)
chunk1<-trees[1:10,]
chunk2<-trees[11:20,]
chunk3<-trees[21:31,]
a <- biglm(ff,chunk1)
a <- update(a,chunk2)
a <- update(a,chunk3)
```

The fitted model is in `a`, from which we extract the variance-covariance matrix of the parameters, drop the intercept, compute the correlation matrix `R` and its determinant:

```
v <- vcov(a)
## drop intercept
v <- v[-1, -1, drop = FALSE]
R <- cov2cor(v)
detR <- det(R)
```

Next, have something to hold the VIFs in

```
res <- numeric(length = ncol(v))
names(res) <- colnames(v)
```

Finally, loop over the model terms (minus intercept) and compute the VIF for each term

```
for(i in seq_len(ncol(v))) {
    res[i] <- det(R[i, i, drop = FALSE]) * det(R[-i, -i, drop = FALSE]) / detR
}
```

This results in:

```
> res
 log(Girth) log(Height) 
   1.391027    1.391027
```

If we load the **car** package and use it to compute VIFs for the same model fitted using `lm()`, we can see that it gives the same output

```
> require(car)
> mod <- lm(ff, data = trees)
> vif(mod)
 log(Girth) log(Height) 
   1.391027    1.391027
```

`vif()` looks a bit cleverer than the code I show as it works out if model terms are included in more coefficients than just the one main effect that my code assumes. In such circumstances, a model covariate will be included in more than one column/row of variance-covariance matrix `v` and you need to retain/exclude all row/columns containing the term when computing the determinants in the `for()` loop. You can work this out from the variance-covariance matrix but you can figure that out yourself.

When testing this, fit your model to a small random sample of the data using both `biglm()` and `lm()`, and compute the VIFs using **car**'s `vif()` on the resulting `"lm"` object and by hand on the `"biglm"` object and check they concur.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson. Made go back to my books. Simplifications seem possible. Once you have the correlation matrix, wouldn't the VIFs be immediately: 1/(1-R^2)?

Comment: @DWin yes, it would. However, if a term is included in more than one column of the `v`, that nice formula wouldn't work, would it? Hence I tried to copy what `vif()` does but left it as an exercise for the reader to make the core more general. `vif()` works with interactions but your suggestion and my code won;t handle that, hence the comment in the penultimate paragraph.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson Thanks for the detailed explanation. As I have 2000 predictors and no interaction terms in the model, just wondering how fast is the loop for calculating res.

Comment: I've allocated storage for the output object so the loop should be as quick as any other loop-like syntax, except perhaps `lapply()` where more of the loop is done in C. The main issue will be the repeated calls to `det()`. I wager it will be quicker than working out how to get the VIFs without looping (`lapply()` aside, and that won't help if the computational burden is in `det()`), unless you need to do this a *lot* of times.

Comment: If you wanted to, and were sure of your data, you could unbundle `det()` and the call to `determinand()` (study the code for both) and take only the bits you need. `determinant.matrix()` has sanity check code before the call to compiled functions which you might not need (!). Or write your own `det()` (based on `det()`), but which calls `determinant.matrix()` instead of `determinant()` so you avoid the repeated overhead of method dispatch.